# Does querying for a specific value instead of whole documents matter much in terms of speed in MongoDB and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

For example, should I use a specific call when I only need a specific value of a user, or can I just as well retrieve the whole document of the user? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is rather subjective and depends on various factors like:

- average size of a document in your MongoDB collection
- network speed and normal bandwidth usage parameters
- structure of your server methods for database queries

If your document is rather large, then fetching it entirely would cause unnecessary network overhead -- compared to if you just fetched the key you needed. This can affect your app performance significantly if you are not careful.

Depending on your MongoDB driver, you can use the **projection** parameters to select the fields you need. e.g.

```
database.collection('user').findOne({ _id: 'someid' }, { _id: 0, username: 1 }, 
  function(err, res) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    callback(res);
  });
```

This will return only the `username` of your `user`, and reduce the network overhead accordingly.